# How to show blog posts changing every time after refreshing the page in non-wordpress website?

Tags: php

I have made a page in non-wordpress website which is showing the post from blog of wordpress website, it is working properly. I have added some PHP code in my page.
Now I want that every time I refresh the page it will show different different post every time.

```
<?php 
  define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
  require('blog/wp-load.php');
  query_posts('showposts=4');
?>

<ul style="margin-top:0px">

<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
 <li style="border: 1px solid #edf4fc;margin-bottom:30px">
<div class="img-hover-zoom">
  <a target="_blank" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p>
  <?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      the_post_thumbnail();
    }
  ?>
 </p>
 <div class="content">
 <h4 style="font-size:18px;font-weight:500;"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>

</div>
</a></div>
 </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: _"non-wordpress website"_ - I think the line `require('../blog/wp-load.php');` tell's a different story. You are in fact booting up Wordpress and are using it's functions, so the question should probably be: _"How do I get a random post in Wordpress?"_.

Comment: You are using Wordpress since you include `require('../blog/wp-load.php');` in your code. One way may be to use `query_posts('showposts=4');` with a random number if you want a different page everytime you refresh the page.

Comment: No, I am not using a wordpress, require('../blog/wp-load.php'); blog folder is a wordpress directory in the non-wordpress website and I including it...

Comment: You can use orderby=rand in your query post. query_posts( 'post_type=post&orderby=rand&showposts=4' );

Comment: I have tried this code but it does not changing post after refreshing thr page.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a random post id that is dependent on the length of the wordpress post database.

```
<?php 
  define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
  require('../blog/wp-load.php');
  $post_id = rand(1, last_post_id);
  query_posts('showposts='.$post_id.’);
?>
```

Comment: I want  to show total 4 post in a page which will change every time I refresh the page. Means 4 post will show everytime but changed.

Comment: Try this documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/ . You could make the order, category or date random

Comment: How to show new posts after refreshing of page in non wordpress website not through wordpress website

Comment: <?php 
  define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
  require('../blog/wp-load.php');
 query_posts(array(
  'orderby' => 'rand', 
  'posts_per_page' => 4
));  ?>
  <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  <p><a target="_blank" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more...</a></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>